# Is it possible to redefine the meaning of "word" in vim?

Tags: vim

In vim, string seperated by "-" would be treated as multiple words, so if I name a variable like 'this-is-a-very-long-variable-name', then vim treat that variable name as two words, so I can easily locate to the start or ending of "variable" and "name".

However, in most programming languages, I am not allowed to name a variable like that, the only programming language that support and prefer that name style is Lisp. in most other programming language, I have to use "_" instead.

So, if I have a variable named "this_is_a_very_long_variable_name", is there any way that I could move on that variable name by pressing "w/b/e" to move by word instead of pressing "h/l" to move by characters?

Answer (score 4):

You can change how words behave with `iskeyword`

```
:set iskeyword-=_
```

Comment: Better yet: `:set iskeyword+=^_` (you want to _exclude_ the underscore, not to make it the only keyword character).

Comment: Slick.  I combined that with `autocmd` to make things conditional.  For example, I don't want colons as part of `iskeyword` when I work on Perl files, so I put together `au FileType perl set iskeyword+=^:` in my .vimrc.

Comment: what' s the difference between  set iskeyword-=_  and   set iskeyword+=^_   ?

Answer (score 3):

If this is just for navigation, my [camelcasemotion plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) provides alternative `,w` / `,b` / `,e` motions (and corresponding text objects), but leaves Vim's word definition alone; i.e. you can still change the entire `variable_name` via `iw`. Alternatively, you can also override Vim's built-in motions with the ones from the plugin.

Changing `'iskeyword'` (as suggested by @Rob) may affect syntax highlighting and other plugins, so this would be a less intrusive solution.